# How is this JS function pulling items from the array without the array being called?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code prints out an Ordered List to the page but I cant figure out how the function printList(List) pulls the array items to print.

```
var playList = [
  'I Did It My Way',
  'Respect',
  'Imagine',
  'Born to Run',
  'Louie Louie',
  'Maybellene'
];

function print(message) {
  document.write(message);
}

function printList(list) {
    var listHTML = '<ol>';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        listHTML += '<li>' + list[i] + '</li>';
    }
    listHTML += '</ol>';
    print(listHTML);
}

printList(playList);
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? That all makes sense to me.

Comment: Because it's called with playList as an argument? printList(playList);

Comment: I'm not understanding how the printList function is getting the data from the array.  In my previous excercises to print an array item I needed to  call it like : var shopping = ['carrots'];  console.log(shopping[0]); to print carrots to the log

Comment: this is the array `playList`... you just passed it to the function to print.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. The printList function is just turning it into an ordered list from the array I passed it at the end of the file. Thanks

Comment: @MarQwannBrown don't feel bad, you could name the array as `playListArray` and call the function as `printListHandler`, then you call the function using `printListHandler(playListArray)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printList(nothing);` will pass `nothing` to function printList.

`printList(playList);` will pass `playList` to function printList.

You could name the array as `playListArray` and call the function as `printListHandler`, then you calling the function will be like: `printListHandler(playListArray)`, this way will be less confusing.

```js
var playList = [
  'I Did It My Way',
  'Respect',
  'Imagine',
  'Born to Run',
  'Louie Louie',
  'Maybellene'
];

var nothing = [
  'I dont know',
  '22222',
  '333333'
];

function print(message) {
  document.write(message);
}

function printList(list) {
    var listHTML = '<ol>';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        listHTML += '<li>' + list[i] + '</li>';
    }
    listHTML += '</ol>';
    print(listHTML);
}

printList(nothing);
```